# Múltiple insert en MyQSL Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

estoy iniciando con laravel y estoy tratando de hacer un múltiple insert a una base de datos. Esto lo estoy tratando de hacer con un formulario que mediante un bucle foreach me crea los inputs con los campos necesarios y sus datos traídos de la base de datos MySQL. He encontrado algunas respuestas en este foro, pero nada funciona en mi caso, no logro encontrar cual es mi error. Agradezco si alguien me puede brindar cualquier información.

**Vista**

```html
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('title', 'Liquidar nueva nomina')

@section('titulo')
    <h1>Liquidar nueva nomina</h1>
    @endsection

@section('contenido')
<section class="contenido">
    <form action="/nomina" method="post">
        @csrf
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
        @foreach($empleados as $empleado)
            //Con este bucle creo el form con los datos de los empleados
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input readonly name="documento_empleado" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$empleado->numero_documento}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input readonly name="nombre_empleado" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$empleado->nombres . ' ' . $empleado->apellidos}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="dias_laborados" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Dias Laborados" value="7" min="0">
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
    </form>
</section>
    @endsection
```

esto es lo que estoy intentando en la funcion store del controller

```html
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $nominas = [];
        foreach ($data as $datas) {
            $nomina['documento_empleado'] = $datas->documento_empleado;
            $nomina['nombre_empleado'] = $datas->nombre_empleado;

            $nominas[] = $nomina;
        }

        Nomina::insert($nominas);
    }
```

Comment: Indicanos por favor cual es tu error, pero a simple vista parece ser que la razón se debe a que no estas usando modelos. Crea un modelo para la tabla a la que quieres hacerle la inserción y define la variable $filleable; es una propiedad que te permitirá definir que columnas de tu base de datos podrán recibir asignaciones en masas. Para aprender más puedes consultar https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment .Suerte.

Comment: Saludos, si tengo el modelo con la variable $filleable y las columnas que quiero llenar, el error que me sale es el siguiente: "Trying to get property 'documento_empleado' of non-object" y la variable esta de la siguiente manera: protected $fillable=['documento_empleado', 'nombre_empleado', 'dias_laborados'];

Comment: Este error (Trying to get property 'documento_empleado' of non-object) se produce generalmente cuando estas tratando de usar un array como si fuera un objeto, puedes darle un dd() a tu variable para que veas lo que esta trayendo.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente pude resolver el problema de la siguiente manera:

```
if (($this->verificarRegistro($request->input_fecha_inicial)) === 0){
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $numeroDeEmpladosActivos; $i++){

            $numero_documento = 'numero_documento' . $i;
            $nombre_empleado = 'nombre_empleado'.$i;                

            DB::table('nominas')->insert(array(
                array('numero_documento'=>$request->$numero_documento,'nombre_empleado'=>$request->$nombre_empleado,),
            ));
        }
        return back()->with('mensaje', 0);
    } else {
        return back()->with('mensaje', 1);
    }
}
```